# I want to add stickers from a folder

Tags: android, photoeditorsdk

I have 100+ png files I need to add as stickers.  I would like to place them in a folder i.e. "/assets/stickers" or in "res/raw".  But i have been unable to figure out how to then read the File/Uri for these images to create the ImageStickerAsset and ImageStickerItem lists.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. put the sticker png into `res/drawable-nodpi/`, not `res/raw/` 
   (because loading of images in `drawable-nodpi` is faster)
2. Add the stickers as ImageStickerAsset's like this

   `AssetConfig assetConfig = settingsList.getConfig();
   assetConfig.addAsset(new ImageStickerAsset(
       "sticker_FILE_NAME",
       ImageSource.create(R.drawable.file_name)
   ));`
3. Create previews from you sticker, with max 196x196px, prefix the files with something like "_preview" and put they also into res/drawable-nodpi/
4. Add a `StickerCategoryItem("category_NAME", R.string.categoryName, ImageSource.create(R.drawable.file_name_preview), ...)`
5. Replace `...` with your ImageStickerItem's (must have the same ID as the assets) and separate the items with a commas

`new ImageStickerItem("sticker_FILE_NAME", R.string.myname, ImageSource.create(R.drawable.file_name_preview)),`

6. Look here for a better example: https://docs.photoeditorsdk.com/guides/android/v6/features/stickers